# UITabBarControler inside Custom Container

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

i have been trying to put two controllers in the Container Controller.

First Controler

1) Just a View Controller  with Few buttons

2) UITabBarController.

Below is the code snippet..

```
tabc = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

hvc = [[HeaderViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HeaderViewController" bundle:nil];
[self addChildViewController:hvc];
[self.view addSubview:hvc.view];
[hvc didMoveToParentViewController:self];


bvc = [[BodyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BodyViewController" bundle:nil];
bvc1 = [[Body1ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Body1ViewController" bundle:nil];


UITabBar *tabBar = tabc.tabBar;
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [ tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [ tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];

tabBarItem1.title = @"fruits";
tabBarItem2.title = @"vegs";

tabc.viewControllers = @[bvc,bvc1];


[self addChildViewController:tabc];
[self.view addSubview:tabc.view];
[tabc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Problem:

In the tab view controller, only one tab is visible at a time [ i.e.: First tab ]

**NOTE:** My mistake, it shows both the tab,  but the table name, or boundary of the tabs 
are not visible. it shows as if the same tab. How to solve this issue ?

What is the quirk i need to be aware of ?.

Comment: Can down voter provide opportunity to me to find out what was the problem with question?. Probably StackOverflow should have  a mandator option to get reason for down voting?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a strange quirk that has bitten many.  Tab bar controllers can only be the root controller and cannot be a child to the container.  This is in apple's docs here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

The section of interest is "The Views of a Tab Bar Controller"

The weird part is it can look like it works ok, but strange behaviors will crop up here and there.